# Create class reflection if constructor argument is heir class

Tags: spring, reflection

**Question**: How can I properly create class reflection, if class constructor contains heir class argument? 
I have:

```
interface Car {}
class SportCar implement Car{}
class CarService {
  public CarService(String str, Car car) {
     ...
  }
}
```

But, when I try to do:

```
Class c = Class.forName("vbspring.model.CarService");
Class[] paramTypes = {String.class, SportCar.class};
Constructor constr = c.getDeclaredConstructor(paramTypes);
```

it throws: **java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: vbspring.model.CarService.(java.lang.String, vbspring.model.SportCar)**

P.S. My .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="carService" class="model.CarService">
        <constructor-arg value="Car Rental Service"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="sportCar"/>
        <property name="startCar"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sportCar" class="model.SportCar"/>

</beans>
```

**EDIT**: I try to write something like my own Spring Framework. I must create not only classes that belongs to Car hierarchy, so I try to write universal method that can create class of arbitrary type. 
I can't write: `Class[] paramTypes = {String.class, Car.class};`

I must write something universal, like:

```
paramTypes[index++] = obj.getClass();
```

where obj - is SportCar or Car bean pulled from .xml by parser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: vbspring.model.CarService.(java.lang.String, vbspring.model.SportCar)` states you have no constructor like:

```
public CarService(String, SportCar)
```

which you don't. You have:

```
public CarService(String, Car) {
```

Change your code to

```
Class c = Class.forName("vbspring.model.CarService");
Class[] paramTypes = {String.class, Car.class}; // the constructor takes Car not SportsCar
Constructor constr = c.getDeclaredConstructor(paramTypes);
```

Then when you call the constructor to get a new instance, you can pass a `SportsCar` instance or any other `Car` instance for that matter.

```
constr.newInstance("sport", new SportsCar());
// or
constr.newInstance("a jeep", new Jeep());
// or
constr.newInstance("long car", new Limousine());
```

assuming `Jeep` and `Limousine` implement `Car`.

Comment: I can't do so,. because I want to write something like my own spring framework, and I should use this code for all reflection types. Can I automatically convert SubClass to SuperClass or SuperInterface?

Comment: @AndrewMelnuk I don't understand what you're trying to say _I can't do so_. Why not? You `CarService` constructor takes a `Car` instance as an argument. That is it's method definition. When you retrieve it through reflection, you need to use that definition.

Comment: I create all objects in my SAX parser, so I get class of object automatically: 'paramTypes[index++] = obj.getClass();'. So I don't know if current object is of Car, SportCar class. It also can belong to another hierarchy (not Car).

Comment: @AndrewMelnuk Whatever it is, you need to retrieve a `Constructor` instance based on the definition of the constructor itself. You can have the most general type as a parameter and then use `instanceof` to check the correct type, but that's ugly as hell. Define a better interface for your CarService (which should only take Car instances).

Comment: Explain me please, what you mean by 'define a better interface for your CarService'? More details or some example, please.

Comment: @AndrewMelnuk Is the example I have posted in my answer not good enough for what you are trying to do?

Comment: @AndrewMelnuk You need to understand that `c.getDeclaredConstructor(paramTypes);` only gets the constructor. So `paramTypes` need to contain the actual type parameters of the constructor you are trying to retrieve. Afterwards, you can pass `obj` you've gotten from the xml as `constr.newInstance("some string", obj);`

Comment: yes, but obj is SportCar. I need a way to automaticaly check if there exist constructor with Car argument, and if exist - call it

Comment: Then use a `try/catch` for `NoSuchMethodException`. Is there any special logic you need to do if it's a `SportsCar` or other type of `Car`?

Comment: No, no special logic. But it must applies for all my classes, not only for Car hierarchy.

Comment: @AndrewMelnuk Obviously, if it isn't `Car` hierarchy, then it should not be using `CarService`. Maybe have a [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) class that decides which Service to use depending on the class type.